# Chart.js with meta tag viewport doesn't work well on iOs or Android device

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I have done many tries but I can't find a good solution. I'm using chart.js on my web application and it should work well both on mobile and desktop.
When I have added the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` the graphs don't render well on the smartphone, both android and iOs.
The graphs are very tiny and so are useless.

How should I configure the canvas or the graph to show well in these device?

Here two examples on a Samsung S8.

[Without meta tag viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X1Tb.jpg)

[With meta tag viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/085g0.jpg)

Comment: you mean you used the "viewport" meta tag? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>`

Comment: Yes I used the "viewport" meta tag